# c#: IsNullableType helper class?

Tags: c#

Can anyone help?

I have some code that is shared between 2 projects. The code points to a model which basically is a collection of properties that comes from a db.

Problem being is that some properties use nullable types in 1 model and the other it doesn't

Really the dbs should use the same but they don't ..

so for example there is a property called IsAvailble which uses "bool" in one model and the other it uses bool? (nullable type)

so in my code i do the following

```
 objContract.IsAvailble.Value ? "Yes" : "No"   //notice the property .VALUE as its a bool? (nullable type)
```

but this line will fail on model that uses a standard "bool" (not nullable) as there is no property .VALUE on types that are NOT nullable

Is there some kind of helper class that i check if the property is a nullable type and i can return .Value  .. otherwise i just return the property.

Anybody have a solution for this?

**EDIT**

This is what i have now.....  i am checking HasValue in the nullable type version

public static class NullableExtensions
    {
        public static T GetValue(this T obj) where T : struct
        {
            return obj;
        }
        public static T GetValue(this Nullable obj) where T : struct
        {
            return obj.Value;
        }

```
    public static T GetValue<T>(this T obj, T defaultValue) where T : struct
    {
        return obj;
    }

    public static T GetValue<T>(this Nullable<T> obj, T defaultValue) where T : struct
    {
        if (obj.HasValue)
            return obj.Value;
        else
            return defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a very good Contract you've got there...

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments, But the bool? was just an example.. I also have many different types that could be nullable or not i.e. int, int?, DateTime, DateTime? ....  I was hoping soemthing generic

Comment: Hi kobi, yes i know its not ideal.... but its code that i have to use currently... in the future i will change it

Comment: Do you *know* that the nullable version, in fact, actually has a value?

Comment: How do you "Share" the code? The more I think of it, the less I get it... You don't *copy* it, do you?

Comment: Hi Kobi, the code is a model that is created automatically from the DB using entity framework and T4.... the model "SHOULD" be the same in each db BUT its "NOT"... very bad... i trying to improve it.. its not my code.... but i have the job of improving it....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little weird, but maybe you can use an extension method here:

```
static class NullableExtensions
{
    public static T GetValue<T>(this T obj) where T : struct
    {
        return obj;
    }
    public static T GetValue<T>(this Nullable<T> obj) where T : struct
    {
        return obj.Value;
    }
}
```

They will work with nullable or regular types:

```
int? i = 4;
int j = 5;

int a = i.GetValue();
int b = j.GetValue();
```

Comment: +1 For flexibility because, as stated, bool might not be the only type.

Comment: the "i.GetValue()" will fail if "i" is null. But you could modify the methodbody to "return obj == null ? default(T) : obj.Value;"

Comment: @Hans - it will. You need to check for nulls (though, that is problematic for the OP), or return `default(T)`. no magic here. Maybe you want an exception in this case? Anyway, that's an important point. I see someone already asked the OP.

Comment: You might want to add an additional parameter to the signatures for the value to return in the event that a) it is a nullable, and b) it is in fact null. e.g. (this T obj, T default). This parameter would be ignored by the plain struct version.

Comment: @Damien - Good idea. Again, I didn't mind null check because the question doesn't refer to that, but that is a good solution.

Comment: Wow! this is great! @Damien, so adding a param of T default i would pass in what i would like it to be if the case is  null.... so hence   i.GetValue(0) for example?? so if its null then it would return 0 ..

Comment: @Mark - Thanks. Yes, that's the idea. You can add another parameter and use it as you've said. You probably want 4 overloads then...

Comment: Thanks Kobi, why 4 overloads out of interest? I will update my question with what i have... which i think serves no???   I would appreciate why i should have 4 overloads..

Comment: Not mandatory, I assumed you want `(this T obj)`, `(this Nullable<T> obj)`, `(this T obj, T defaultValue)`, `(this Nullable<T> obj, T defaultValue)`. Anyway, I think you got the point. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't cast. use the  `??` operator

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224(VS.80).aspx

```
bool? isAvailble = null;

//string displayIsAvailble = (bool)(isAvailble) ? "Yes" : "No"; //exception Nullable object must have a value.

string displayIsAvailble = (isAvailble ?? false) ? "Yes" : "No";  //outputs "no"

Console.WriteLine(displayIsAvailble);
```

Answer (score 0):

`(bool)(objContract.IsAvailble) ? "Yes" : "No"`

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToBoolean(objContract.IsAvailble) ? "yes" : "no"
```

OR

Is this what you are looking for?

```
bool? n = false;
bool nn = true;

Console.WriteLine(n ?? nn);
```

Answer (score 0):

One more alternative:

```
objContract.IsAvailble == true ? "Yes" : "No"
```

On the nullable, only true is true, null or false is false.  On the regular bool, true/false is normal.

Comment: Cannot not convert bool? to bool

Comment: @mark - Works here in every case, not sure what your compiler's complaining about :-/

Answer (score 0):

Best I can suggest is to always cast to the nullable, then use the null coalescing operator to say what you want the value to be when it's null. e.g.:

```
    string s3 = (bool?)b ?? false ? "yes" : "no";
```

The above will work whether b is defined as bool or bool?

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
bool? b1 = objContract.IsAvailable;
string s1 = b1.Value ? "Yes" : "No";`
```

This should work whether `objectContract.IsAvailable` is a `bool` or `bool?` or any other nullable type.

For dates for example:

```
DateTime? t1 = objContract.EitherNullableOrNotNullableDate;
string s1 = t1.Value.ToString();
```